# filtering out string dates in python list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list that contains dictionaries(my_list) that looks like

```
[{'name': 'jane', 'number': 123, 'birthday': '04/05/78'}, 
 {'name': 'summer', 'number': 542, 'birthday': '07/01/1990'},
 {'name': 'carter', 'number': 003, 'birthday': '12/15/1992'}]
```

I am trying to filter out results by a birthday

```
my_filter = [elf for elf in my_list if 'birthday' >= '01/01/1980']
```

This should eliminate the first entry but when i print out my filter all three entries are still being printed.

How can i compare the string dates (birthday) to filter out data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datetime.strptime` to parse the date strings into `datetime` objects for comparison. Since the year portions of your date strings are inconsistently formatted, you should normalize them first with a regex substitution:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re
my_list = [{'name': 'jane', 'number': 123, 'birthday': '04/05/78'},
 {'name': 'summer', 'number': 542, 'birthday': '07/01/1990'},
 {'name': 'carter', 'number': 3, 'birthday': '12/15/1992'}]
print([elf for elf in my_list if datetime.strptime(re.sub(r'\d\d(\d\d)$', r'\1', elf['birthday']), '%m/%d/%y') >= datetime(1980, 1, 1)])
```

This outputs:

```
[{'name': 'summer', 'number': 542, 'birthday': '07/01/1990'}, {'name': 'carter', 'number': 3, 'birthday': '12/15/1992'}]
```